# VBA/VBE: Looping through all files in a folder, pulling text and populating to spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, text-files, filesystemobject, vbe

I'm trying to create a VBE program that will open all files in a folder, pull out text specific text that appears in predictable places in all the files, and populate the text variables to a spreadsheet.

My issue is that I can't get the text variables to update to reflect the content of each file.  Instead, I get the text variable associated with File # 1, all the way down the column.

Among other tinkering, I tried using FreeFile instead of explicitly numbering files, all to no avail.  Guidance much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Looping()

Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object, i As Integer

Dim text As String, Dim textline As String, Dim Author As String, Dim AuthPos As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files")

i = 1

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

Open objFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

Author = InStr(text, ", Author.")
Author = Mid(text, Author - 15, Author)
Author = Left(Author, 15)
AuthPos = InStr(Author, ".")
Author = Right(Author, Len(Author) - AuthPos)

Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
Cells(i + 1, 3) = Author
i = i + 1

Next objFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies, all, I found an excellent answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851974/extract-a-single-line-of-data-from-numerous-text-files-and-import-into-excel

Answer (score 0):

Your sub works!!!

Just add the following line before going for the next loop:

```
text = vbNullString
```

The `text` variable was not emptied, therefore it was always appended with data from other files, so the last file contained the data from all the files before it.