# Extract Data from Text File into Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA so getting my task done is quite a struggle. Been reading and trying codes from different threads for a few days now to no success. So I am hoping someone could assist me.

I have multiple text files that I need to extract data from. But I only need certain data such as DATE-TIME to be placed in the 1st column and CARD NUMBER in the 2nd column. Got codes from this thread >> [Extract a single line of data from numerous text files and import into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851974/extract-a-single-line-of-data-from-numerous-text-files-and-import-into-excel) but my output only shows the first data from the file. Please see the attached files below.

[sample text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKEYc.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAD3W.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC7p4.png)

Here's what I have:

```
Sub ExtractData()
Dim filename As String, nextrow As Long, MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String, text As String, textline As String, filedate As String
Dim filenum As Integer

MyFolder = "C:\directory\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.txt")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline

    Loop
    Close #1
    MyFile = Dir()
    Debug.Print text
    filedate = InStr(text, "DATE-TIME")
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(nextrow, "A").value = Mid(text, filedate + 16, 17)

    filenum = InStr(text, "CARD NUMBER")
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(nextrow, "B").value = Mid(text, filenum + 16, 10)
    text = ""  
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) to extract data by any pattern. Regular Expressions is a mighty tool for such things.

Comment: @PEH Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: Why write VBA at all? You are asking to *import* a file into Excel. You can do that using the commands in the `Data` tab and use PowerQuery to clean up, transform the data

Comment: BTW `Line Input`, `Close` etc aren't used in VBA. They are leftovers from VB5 or even earlier. Since the VB6 days people are using `FileSystemObject` and the other classes in the Scripting Runtime. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba). Excel's own data input functionality though is far more powerful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify the code for you, it can work:

```
Sub ExtractData()
Dim filename As String, nextrow As Long, MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String, text As String, textline As String, filedate As String
Dim filenum As Integer
dim idx%

MyFolder = "C:\directory\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.txt")

nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Do While MyFile <> ""

    Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1

    'nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline 'read a line

        idx = InStr(textline, "DATE-TIME") ' if has date, set it but not move to the next ROW
        if idx > 0 then 
            ActiveSheet.Cells(nextrow, "A").value = Mid(textline, idx + 16)
        end if

        idx = InStr(textline, "CARD NUMBER")
        if idx > 0 then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(nextrow, "B").value = Mid(textline, filenum + 16)

            nextrow = nextrow + 1 'now move to next row

        end if

    Loop
    Close #1
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! That's awesome! Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. You're the best! :)

Comment: Yup, just did. Thanks again. :)