# File not advancing for Line Input in VBA

Tags: vba

This code intends to loop through a folder with multiple .txt files, then write a string from the file name into column 1 and a string from within the text file itself (it is in a fixed position) into column 2 using the Line Input function.

It returns the correct list in column 1, but column 2 is getting the value from the first file in each cell rather than the unique value from each file.

The objfile obviously advances, since the first column is getting a new value each time.  And the
Line Input obviously accepts the file as called since it retrieves the value from the first fine/
Why does it not also advance for the Line Input section?

```
Sub ImportFileNames()

'Declarations
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim TextLine As String
Dim text As String

'Clears out old data
ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Columns(2).ClearContents

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\bbnewman\Desktop\Order Entry\EDIOrders")
i = 1

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    If (objFile.DateCreated < Date - 183) Or (Right(objFile.Name, 3) <> "txt") Then
    
        i = i + 1 'Skips noncompliant files
        
    Else
        
        'print body #
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = Left(objFile.Name, 7)
        
        
        'print PO#
        Open objFile For Input As #1
        
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            text = text & TextLine
            Loop
        
        
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Mid(text, 121, 9)
        
        Close #1
        
    i = i + 1
    
    End If

Next objFile

'Deletes blank lines
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there some kind of competition or test going on? This is the 3rd time I've seen this project today. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28851974/14608750) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69315777/14608750)

Comment: Weird!  If there is, I don't know anything about it.  Mine just came up from something I was trying to do for work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write `text = text & TextLine` , that means `text` will keep it's content and the new `Textline` is added at it's end. With other words, `text` gets longer and longer, but the beginning never changes.

All you have to do is to reset `text` for every file: Put a statement `text = ""` before you start reading the file.

```
    Open objFile For Input As #1
    text = ""
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TextLine
        text = text & TextLine
    Loop
```

Comment: Thank you.  I actually need that "& TextLine" so it records all of the text in the document rather than stopping after the firstcarriage return.  The string I need is further down the page.  BUT you did help me realize that each iteration continued to add to the string.  So I added the line 

         text = ""

after Close #1.  That way, when it loops back through, it pulls the text down into a blank variable rather than adding it to what was recorded last time through.  That fixed it.

THANKS!