# Extract multiple lines of data from numerous text files and correlate into Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Any suggestions on how to modify the script from:

[Extract a single line of data from numerous text files and import into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851974/extract-a-single-line-of-data-from-numerous-text-files-and-import-into-excel)

To generate an excel sheet that has the file name in one column (the file name of the .ini file), the Latitude in a second column and the Longitude in the third column? I also have a bunch of .ini files that contain camera parameters for a .jpg, but need to extract the Name, Lat and Long for further processing.

Here is a sample of the .ini file:

---

```
[top_left]
lng =  -80.5251854921
lat =   46.6276919869

[top_right]
lng =  -80.5307483620
lat =   46.6297628116

[bottom_left]
lng =  -80.5229096407
lat =   46.6307857000

[bottom_right]
lng =  -80.5281836560
lat =   46.6327636148

[center]
lng =  -80.5267096969
lat =   46.6302821844

[origin]
Xs =       319.50000
Ys =       239.50000

[map]
A00 =         0.0008197901
A01 =        -0.0085907931
A02 =       -80.5267154968
A10 =        -0.0004764527
A11 =         0.0049839176
A12 =        46.6302857603
A20 =        -0.0000102856
A21 =         0.0001067452
A22 =         1.0000000000

[frameTimestamp]
frameTs = 0
```

---

I tried using some of the code from [extract data from multiple text files in a folder into excel worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610422/extract-data-from-multiple-text-files-in-a-folder-into-excel-worksheet) with little success.

Comment: What the output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want - but there's no error processing - it assumes that each file is laid out as you've shown in your example.  Also I'm assuming any of the lat/lng pairs are okay and that you only want one of them; hence, I extract the one associated with 'top_left'.  Also all .ini files are in C:Temp\Test directory and assumes that you want the data appended after the last row in the ActiveSheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractLatLng()
    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String, textline As String
    Dim r As Integer, pos As Integer

    MyFolder = "C:\Temp\Test\"
    MyFile = dir(MyFolder & "*.ini")

    r = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
          Line Input #1, textline
          pos = InStr(textline, "[top_left]")
          If pos = 1 Then
             ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value = MyFile
             Line Input #1, textline
             pos = InStr(textline, "=")
             ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "C").Value = Mid(textline, pos + 1)
             Line Input #1, textline
             pos = InStr(textline, "=")
             ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "B").Value = Mid(textline, pos + 1)
             r = r + 1
             Exit Do
          End If
        Loop
        Close #1
        MyFile = dir()
    Loop 
End Sub
```